# SharePoint: how to create a thumbnail design?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

[image]

I would like to create clickable image thumbnails like that shown below in SharePoint 2013. The point being, easily clickable categories from our homepage. How can I go about doing this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **Promoted Links** list template.

Take a look here: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/08/01/sharepoint-2013-add-custom-tiles-to-sharepoint-site-page/

and here (for customization): http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19622.sharepoint-2013-promoted-links-wrap-tiles.aspx

or here (for customization): http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26522.everything-about-promoted-links-in-sharepoint-2013-change-size-wrap-view-handle-click-event-using-jquery.aspx